# How to convert image from Base64String to byte[] array in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to convert image into byte array. Here is my code which returns base64String of that image:

```
 $scope.imageAdded = function (files) {
        angular.forEach(files,
            function (flowFile, i) {
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = function (event) {
                    var uri = event.target.result;
                    $scope.imageStrings[i] = uri;
                };
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(flowFile.file);
                event.preventDefault(); //prevent file from uploading
            });
    }
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $scope.base64toByteArray = function(b64Data, contentType = '', sliceSize = 512) => {
        const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
        const byteArrays = [];
    
        for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
          const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
    
          const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
          for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
          }
    
          const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
          byteArrays.push(byteArray);
        } 
        return byteArrays;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$scope.imageAdded = async function imageAdded (flowFiles) {
    const arrayBuffer = await flowFiles[0].file.arrayBuffer()
    const uint8array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)
}
```

Comment: you can thank people by accepting a answer as a accepted solution and giving them +1 (at the left side). By doing so you will let others know that this question have been answered and you got what you were looking for. it will also help others know which one is the best/correct way of solving similar issues when they found you exact same problem

Comment: yeah! whatever you are saying is absolutely right. But my reputation is less than 10 so according to the website's rule, I can't vote :(

Comment: Anyone who can _ask_ a question can mark an answer as accepted even if you can't yet upvote. (See [What does it mean to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for information) @AliHamza